# Cannot connect Emissions Impact Dashboard to Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi

I am trying to connect my data to the [Emissions Impact Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-connect-to-emissions-impact-dashboard) in Power BI.

I have an MCA/MPA Azure account and I am trying with a user having **Global Admin** role, hence I believe I meet the requirements:

- A Power BI Pro license.
- An admin role with read/write permissions on your Azure tenant.
- If you have an MCA/MPA account, you must be a Billing Account Administrator with a role as Billing Account Reader/Contributor/Owner, and have your company's billing account ID.

Nevertheless we get the `Refresh failed` error message. How can I troubleshoot? [Issues at GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20emissions) seem to be left unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now suddenly the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-connect-to-emissions-impact-dashboard) is updated with this information:

> This connector version only supports enrollments from the Azure Enterprise portal.

Totally confusing documentation, and [many people](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi/coi-sustainability.emissions_impact_dashboard?tab=Reviews) seems to share my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing after 24-48 hours as per the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-connect-to-emissions-impact-dashboard#prerequisites
[image]

Comment: Still doesn't work, even after a couple of days.